# Ember js iterate in model and check if value exists

Tags: javascript, ember.js

This is the code sample from my application

Discussion Model

```
App.Discussion = Ember.Model.extend({
    id: Ember.attr(),
    title: Ember.attr(),
    body: Ember.attr(),
    course_id: Ember.attr(),
    replies: Ember.hasMany('App.Reply', {key:'replies', embedded: 'load'}),
    creator_id: Ember.attr(),
    creator_first_name: Ember.attr(),
    creator_last_name: Ember.attr(),
    status: Ember.attr(),
    created_at: Ember.attr(),
    accepted_answer_id: Ember.attr()
});
```

Reply Model

```
App.Reply = Ember.Model.extend({
    id: Ember.attr(),
    body: Ember.attr(),
    discussion_id: Ember.attr(),
    discussion: Ember.belongsTo('App.Discussion', {key: 'discussion_id'}),
    creator_id: Ember.attr(),
    creator_first_name: Ember.attr(),
    creator_last_name: Ember.attr(),
    status: Ember.attr(),
    created_at: Ember.attr()
});

App.Discussion.Controller = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  hasSomething: function() {
   // Here I want to check whether user_id = 101 in the replies array of the discussion Model. 
 // If any of the replies has the user_id as 101 return true.
  }.property('id')

});
```

I tried getting the replies into an array and then iterating and checking over it.

```
replies = this.get('model.replies');

        replies.forEach(function(reply) {
           console.log(reply.get('creator_id'));
            if (window.userId === reply.get('creator_id')) {
                // do stuff here.
            }
        });
```

Is there any better/EMBER WAY way to acheive this  ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember has some nice helpers on their [Array-object](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html) (also available on regular arrays unless you disable prototype extensions).

[Array.isAny()](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_isAny) might be worth looking at.

```
hasSomething: function() {
  // Here I want to check whether user_id = 101 in the replies array of the discussion Model. 
  // If any of the replies has the user_id as 101 return true.
  var replies = this.get('model.replies');
  return replies.isAny('creator_id', window.userId);
}.property('model.replies.@each')
```

You might also want to set the property to actually observe the replies-array using `model.replies.@each`.